# Count length of bold word in string

Tags: excel, vba

Can anyone help me?

I have a string: **CLR**. CLR is the most...

I want to get length of bold word

Comment: Please add the application, you're asking for (Word, Excel, PowerPoint, Visio, ...).

Comment: @Ququruzik you could see the edited answer on your yesterday question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify the below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim j As Long, Count As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Change sheet name if needed

        'Lets say string appears in cell A1
        For j = 1 To Len(.Range("A1").Value)

            If .Range("A1").Characters(j, 1).Font.FontStyle = "Bold" Then
                Count = Count + 1
            End If

        Next j

        Debug.Print Count

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: the `count` provide the length of the BOLD characters

Comment: @Error1004 - Hint to internationalization: I'd suggest to use `If .Range("A4").Characters(j, 1).Font.Bold Then` as `.Font.FontStyle` returns the word *"bold"* in the current regional setting (in German e.g. "Fett" instead of "Bold" :-)